# Data Factory Copy Activity met storage failure at source side - AppendBlob was not found

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Error:
**Copy activity met storage operation failure at 'Source' side. Error message from storage execution : Requested value 'AppendBlob' was not found..**

I was originally trying to copy a blob to on prem sql and I received the above error.  Just for testing I am trying to copy blob to blob and I still received the same error.

I can see the blob in my container.  But it seems like azure data factory copy activity cannot access it.  Do **AppendBlobs** work with azure data factory copy activity?  Any one else run into this issue, any ideas on how to resolve?

Thanks.

Azure Data Factory JSON definition files:

InputBlob:

```
{
"name": "InputBlobTest",
"properties": {
    "published": false,
    "type": "AzureBlob",
    "linkedServiceName": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
    "typeProperties": {
        "fileName": "ContractHeader.csv",
        "folderPath": "testcontainer/",
        "format": {
            "type": "TextFormat",
            "rowDelimiter": "\n",
            "columnDelimiter": ","
        }
    },
    "availability": {
        "frequency": "Hour",
        "interval": 1
    },
    "external": true,
    "policy": {
        "externalData": {
            "retryInterval": "00:01:00",
            "retryTimeout": "00:10:00",
            "maximumRetry": 3
        }
    }
}
```

OuputBlob:

```
{
"name": "OutputBlobTest",
"properties": {
    "published": false,
    "type": "AzureBlob",
    "linkedServiceName": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
    "typeProperties": {
        "fileName": "Sample.csv",
        "folderPath": "testcontainer/",
        "format": {
            "type": "TextFormat",
            "rowDelimiter": "\n",
            "columnDelimiter": ","
        }
    },
    "availability": {
        "frequency": "Hour",
        "interval": 1
    }
}
```

Pipeline:

```
{
"name": "PipelineBlobToBlob",
"properties": {
    "description": "Copy data from a blob to Azure SQL table",
    "activities": [
        {
            "type": "Copy",
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "BlobSource",
                    "skipHeaderLineCount": 1
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "BlobSink",
                    "writeBatchSize": 0,
                    "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00"
                }
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "InputBlobTest"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "OutputBlobTest"
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "01:00:00",
                "concurrency": 1,
                "executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst"
            },
            "scheduler": {
                "frequency": "Hour",
                "interval": 1
            },
            "name": "CopyFromBlobToBlob",
            "description": ""
        }
    ],
    "start": "2015-07-12T00:00:00Z",
    "end": "2015-07-12T01:00:00Z",
    "isPaused": false
}
```

Comment: I see that the `writeBatchSize` and `writeBatchTimeout` both are 0. Can you try increasing `writeBatchSize` it to say 1000 and `writeBatchTimeout` to 00:10:00

Comment: That's interesting because that was the default when I saved because I never defined those properties.  Now I am retrying and I can no longer get the append blob input to validate, not sure why that is.  It just says "conflict" for the validation error.  Also interesting if I change my input data set to point to a BlockBlob it validates and runs fine even with the batch size set at 0 and timeout set to 00:00:00.

Comment: Try removing the file name property from your datasets and just define the blob folder path excluding the file name. See if the copy works as expected.

Comment: First time I got this error but seems to confirm what I suspected: Copy activity met storage operation failure at 'Source' side. Error message from storage execution : The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict. The type of a blob in the container is unrecognized by this version. - So I am going to assume this means appendblobs are not supported yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received confirmation, Append blobs are currently not supported with azure data factory copy activity.